# Any way to tell if a div element is overlapping another with a specific attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can you tell if a div element is overlapping another div element that has a specific attribute, such color? Is there a rather simple way to do this?

I'm making a maze type of game, so I need to know if the avatar or whatever bumps into a wall. (This would all be 2D of course) Also, both elements would be different sizes

Comment: why would you need to know if a div is being overlapped?

Comment: Well I'm making a maze type of game, so I need to know if the avatar or whatever bumps into a wall. (This would all be 2D of course)

Comment: `element.getBoundingClientRect()` will give you the position and size of the element on the screen. To figure out if they're colliding, assuming they're all rectangular, just do some basic math between the two bounding rectangles.

Comment: Usually you would have your state in memory and plot it to a canvas but in your case your state and canvas are both in HTML This will complicate things in the long run. I would advise you to make your game in a HTML canvas. If the gist of your game is HTML elements only then I've said nothing.

Comment: What would the benefit be to use the canvas tag?

Comment: You want to have control over your state so that you know where your object are and how big they are so you can do some basic math to handle the collisions. Plotting to HTML elements can still be a thing but a canvas will perform much better with 2d animations.